# How to install php-cgi as a plugin in Mac OS ( OS X 10.10)?

Tags: php, macos

I want to do PHP works on My **Mac book**. However, after I installed **Php storm**, and tell the **PHP Interpreter**'s location, it causes error:

```
php-cgi not found
Please ensure that configured PHP Interpreter built as CGI program (--enable-fastcgi was specified
```

Obviously, I should install `php-cgi`.

I found an answer on [How do I enable fastcgi on my Mavericks using PHP 5.4.24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667178/how-do-i-enable-fastcgi-on-my-mavericks-using-php-5-4-24). It says I should re-install **PHP** with some options, both **fastcgi**.

```
brew install php54 --with-fpm --with-debug --with-cgi --with-libmysql --with-homebrew-curl
brew install fastcgi
```

I am considering that: Since I have the default **PHP** on my Mac, must I re-install a new **PHP** ? Can I install `*cgi` as a plugin of the default **php** ?

Comment: Was php installed as php-cli? Or is it better to modify settings of PHP Storm?

Answer (score 6):

To get the latest version (or whatever version you already have) on your MacBook, use:

```
brew install php --with-cgi --with-debug --with-libmysql
```

Note that [Benjamin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29461292) is similar. However, it's not ideal to install v54 when I'm already on v717, so using just "php" without the version would get the latest one.

Comment: `Sierra (10.12.6)` returns with `Error: invalid option: --with-cgi`     With  `php -v
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2017 20:30:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies`

Comment: Yes, 2 months ago brew / php in all of it's wisdom removed the "--with-" options i.e. anything with "with" will no longer work (used to before). The latest update is to install the PHP version using the @version instead. i.e. something like brew install php@7.2.19 , this will create a new folder under your /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.19/... and from there you could reference it on your apps. I am doing the same right now, hope that helps.

Comment: @HeiderSati which file are you referring via this path /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.19/...?

Comment: Hi @Tara, the answer I wrote was 6 years ago was for php v7.x, I moved on and now using v8.3.1. Under my /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.1 (or /.../7.2.19 in your case) has all the standard PHP-installed dirs (bin, lib etc) and files, example bin/php, the directory you are referring to and mine also is where the installation is location. I hope this answers your question, let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

As you already said, you installed PHP without `--with-cgi`. The problem is that CGI is an integral part of PHP and therefore needs to be added at compile time. Reinstalling PHP using brew however won't affect your settings in php.ini so there shouldn't be any reason not to reinstall it:

```
brew install php54 --with-cgi --with-debug --with-libmysql {more options here}
```

This does **not** overwrite the default installation of PHP on your Mac. After installation homebrew will show you how to make it start when you start your Mac.

(Sidenote: You should consider upgrading to at least 5.5. Be careful though as this deprecates the use of mysql_* in favor of mysqli_* and PDO. More details about that on http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the answer to this, but I'm not using Storm, and I want the latest version of PHP 5. I was able to get it working using the following:

First, make sure you don't have an old version of gcc laying around from before you upgraded OS X. In my case, I needed to:

```
brew uninstall apple-gcc42
```

Then get the PHP source and install it with CGI enabled:

```
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install --enable-cgi php56
```

I used this to set up a Rack-based project that runs PHP in CGI mode.