# How to enable fastcgi on Yosemite with PHP 5.5.14

Tags: php, cgi, phpstorm, fastcgi

I'm using **PHPStorm 9** on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10 and when I try to open the project in the browser it returns a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

In PHPStorm it says php-cgi not found

```
Please ensure that configured PHP interpreter built as CGI program (--enable-fastcgi was specified)
```

I followed the answer by GotchaRob in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667178/how-do-i-enable-fastcgi-on-my-mavericks-using-php-5-4-24?answertab=active#tab-top), but it didn't help.
Unfortunately I can't post comments yet, so I've created a new question.

I would really appreciate if someone could provide some help.
Thank you.

Comment: What output does `php-fpm -v` give you?

Comment: It returns: `PHP 5.5.14 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:39)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans`

Comment: That is the output you'd want to see. Are you sure you selected the php-fpm binary (usually `/usr/sbin/php-fpm`) as interpreter in your PhpStorm install and not the native php binary?

Comment: as an interpreter I choose `/usr/bin/php` (where php.ini is located) - http://take.ms/pMBLa. If I choose `/usr/sbin/php-fpm` PHPStorm says php is not installed

Answer (score 5):

i fix this problem with this solution

http://barratmp.blogspot.ru/2014/10/the-core-yosemite-php-version-is-5.html

but i install only php5.6

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56
```

after installation pointed the way to php6.5 in phpstorm

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This solved my problem!! My PHPSTORM is now functioning correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me to finally get mine to work! :D

Comment: I did the same. In my PhpStorm I configured the PHP executable to `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.25_1/bin/php`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work with p.Omelchenko's solution, so I tried what is suggested in this [website](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpstorm-tells-me-php-cgi-not-found) by aswin_0348 and it worked like a charm!

Just `sudo apt-get install php7.3-cgi`